# Visual Studio Code: Search in folders with square brackets in their name

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi,

When I wan't to search in a folder folder for something but the folder name has `[]` in it. It doesn't work, anyone know a solution for this?

I was hoping it was as simple as putting a backslash(or double) in front of it.
But it wasn't... Or is this just not possible?...

Greetings Ypsilon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is this issue: ["files to include" doesn't work with folder names containing glob characters](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82415) which remains open.

Update: this is now working in the Insiders Build v1.76, it should be released to Stable v11.76 early March 2023.  The glob characters `[]?*` are escaped in the `files to include` search input when you use the context menu option `Find in Folder...` on a folder or folders in the Explorer.